# Book Recommendation Needed: Gradient Descent, Euler-Lagrange

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations, book-recommendation

On a lecture note I read about Calculus of Variations

faculty.uml.edu/cbyrne/cov.pdf

the author talks about Euler-Lagrange equation, then continues to say "unfortunately, many times a closed form solution [for EL eqn] is not known. One way to cope with this problem is to use a gradient descent technique. Incidentally, the left hand side of the Euler-Lagrange equation can be regarded as an infinite-dimensional gradient".

How did he make this transition, from a EL PDE to gradient descent? Which class, book would cover this subject? My books on Calculus of Variations have nothing on this. Should I look under Optimization, Numerical PDE?

Thanks,

Comment: Maybe in lecture 5 of this set: http://vision.ucla.edu/~ganeshs/dsp_course/

Comment: this looks useful, thanks.

Comment: If you are the book type, "Optimization by Vector Space Methods" by David Luenberger is a well-written classes in this field. He covers both, although I don't remember if he directly connects the two in a chapter.

Comment: Classic, not classes.

Comment: looks like a good source; there is a chapter called "optimization of functionals" which is the kind of info I was looking for.

Comment: @gnometorule the PDF here says the same thing, using the Luenberger book - http://hci.iwr.uni-heidelberg.de/Staff/bgoldlue/fvia_ws_2011/fvia_ws_2011_01_variational_analysis.pdf. I guess I need to understand Functional Analysis in order to proceed on this path.